# Python -function not returning result

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

Trying to build a tool, using python. The tool should do the following things:

Assuming I have two dict -

```
dict() #1 - data
{'name_id': 'manager_id_1', 'name_first': 'manager_name_1', 'direct_report:' [{'name_id': 'employee_id_1', 'name_first': 'employee_name_1', 'direct_report': []}, {'name_id': 'employee_id_2', 'name_first': 'employee_name_2', 'direct_report': []}, {'name_id': 'employee_id_3', 'name_first': 'employee_name_3', 'direct_report': [{'name_id': 'employee_id_3_1', 'name_first': 'employee_name_3_1', 'direct_report': []}, {'name_id': 'employee_id_3_2', 'name_first': 'employee_name_3_2', 'direct_report': []}]}


dict() #2 - data_count
{'employee_id_1': 2, 'xxxx_id': 3, 'employee_id_2': 5, 'xxxx_id': 5, 'employee_id_3_2': 6}
```

first dict includes all the personal info and report structures while the second dict includes the data count group by each individual (include those users in dict 1)

the task is to sum the total and display the total counts under the manager(s) in a new dict, something like this:

```
{manager_name_1: 7}
{employee_name_3: 6}
```

Here is the function I wrote but it is not returning anything. If I remove return result[data_name], I'm getting an error - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'. Trying to debug this today but wasn't able to figure out where I did wrong, any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
def data_recursive(data_sample, data_count_sample):
    result = dict()

    data_user = str
    data_name = str
    data_report = str

    for key, value in data_sample.items(): 
        if 'name_id' in key:
            data_user = value
        elif 'name_first' in key:
            data_name = value
        else:
            data_report = value

            if len(data_report) == 0:
                result[data_name] = data_count_sample.get(data_user, 0)

                return data_count_sample.get(data_user, 0)
            else:
                user_sum = 0
                for data_users in data_report:
                    x = recusive = data_recursive(data_users, data_count_sample)
                    user_sum = user_sum + x

                result[data_name] = data_count_sample.get(data_user, 0) + user_sum
                return result[data_name]

    print(result)
    return(result)
```

Comment: Your posted two dicts are not valid dictionaries. Please correct them.

Comment: Thanks @JohnAnderson - correct the typos

Comment: error should shows you in which line is problem and it also shows that problem is with `None` so use `print()` to check values in variables in this line - ie. `print(user_sum)`, `print(x)` - probably `x` is `None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the desired tally dict, this is my proposal:

```
def data_recursive(data, data_count):
name = data['name_first']
result = {name: 0}
report = data['direct_report']
if report:
    result[name] = sum([data_count.get(r['name_id'], 0) for r in report])
    for d in [data_recursive(reporter, data_count) for reporter in report]:
        for key, value in d.items():
            result[key] = value        
else:
    result[name] = data_count.get(data['name_id'], 0)
return result
```

**Result**

```
 {'manager_name_1': 7,
 'employee_name_1': 2,
 'employee_name_2': 5,
 'employee_name_3': 6,
 'employee_name_3_1': 0,
 'employee_name_3_2': 6}
```

**Notes**

- Some nesting was reduced for clarity, as well as some names
  shortened.
- No need to cycle through the keys, and the id of the
  current iteration is only used once anyway so I skip storing it,
  while report and name are used often.
- Because the sum of the values
  for each person goes only 1 level deep (e.g. employee_id_3_2 is NOT
  to be counted under manager_name_1 given that in the example data the
  total is 7 rather than 13), the sum of values for each person is
  summed separately in line 6, before the recursion that will bubble up
  the names and totals for subordinates into the result dict.
- When someone has no subordinates, the recursion ends and the data is
  gathered.

Answer (score 0):

There are typos, dict format is not correct. Check the corrected code sample.

```
data_sample = { 'name_id': 'manager_id_1',
                'name_first': 'manager_name_1',
                'direct_report': [
                    {
                        'name_id': 'employee_id_1',
                        'name_first': 'employee_name_1',
                        'direct_report': []
                    },
                    { 'name_id': 'employee_id_2',
                      'name_first': 'employee_name_2',
                      'direct_report': []
                    },
                    { 'name_id': 'employee_id_3',
                      'name_first': 'employee_name_3',
                      'direct_report': [{
                                  'name_id': 'employee_id_3_1',
                                  'name_first': 'employee_name_3_1',
                                  'direct_report': []
                                       }]
                    },
                    { 'name_id': 'employee_id_3_2',
                          'name_first': 'employee_name_3_2',
                          'direct_report': []
                    }]
               }

data_count_sample = { 'employee_id_1': 2,
                      'xxxx_id': 3,
                      'employee_id_2': 5,
                      'xxxx_id': 5,
                      'employee_id_3_2': 6 
                    }


def data_recursive(data_sample, data_count_sample):
    result = dict()
    data_user = str
    data_name = str
    for key, value in data_sample.items():
        if 'name_id' in key:
            data_user = value
        elif 'name_first' in key:
            data_name = value
        else:
            data_report = value

            if len(data_report) == 0:
                result[data_name] = data_count_sample.get(data_user, 0)

                return data_count_sample.get(data_user, 0)
            else:
                user_sum = 0
                for data_users in data_report:
                    x = data_recursive(data_users, data_count_sample)
                    user_sum = user_sum + x

                result[data_name] = data_count_sample.get(data_user, 0) + user_sum
                return result[data_name]
    return result


output = data_recursive(data_sample, data_count_sample)
print(output)
```

Output

```
13
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest passing the result dictionary as an argument to the `data_recursive()` method. Changing the signature to:

```
def data_recursive(data_sample, data_count_sample, result):
```

and remove the line:

```
result = dict()
```

Then, when you call the method use:

```
ret = dict()
data_recursive(data_sample, data_count_sample, ret)
```

And the `ret` dict should hold your results.